# alasql and alpine.js: reactivity from updates outside of Alpine

Tags: alpine.js

I would like to use Alpine.js while keeping as much application state inside of alasql.js as possible. The problem is that data which is loaded after `Alpine.start()` does not show up in the `x-for` section. If there is a way to force a wasteful full-refresh (without running `Alpine.start()` again) I would be interested to know. I tried the `customEvents` workaround several times but that did not work.

Is there any other way to make something like this work? Without changing too much of the architecture..? I'm curious / stubborn

```js
    await fetch(`${API_domain}?playlist=` + playlist)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        alasql('ATTACH localStorage DATABASE RuntimeDB')
        alasql('SET AUTOCOMMIT ON')

        alasql(`DELETE from videos where webpage_url = "${data.webpage_url}"`)
        alasql(`INSERT INTO videos SELECT * FROM ?`, [[data]])
        app.updateView()
      })
```

```html
 <div x-data="{
   playlistToAdd: '',
   async submit($event) {
     await app.fetchPlaylist(this.playlistToAdd)
   }
 }">
  <label for="add_new">Add New Playlist or Channel:</label>
  <input type="text" name="add_new" id="add_new" x-model="playlistToAdd"
   placeholder="https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8A83124F1D79BD4F" @keyup.enter="submit" />
  <button type="button" @click="submit">Submit</button>
 </div>

 <div x-data>
  <template x-for="(pl, index) in app.view.table" :key="index">
   <div>
    <details x-html="`<summary><a href='${pl.webpage_url}'>${pl.title}</a> by
     <a href='${pl.channel_url}'>${pl.uploader}</a> (watched ${pl.playlist_count-pl.entries.length} of ${pl.playlist_count}; ${(pl.playlist_count-pl.entries.length)/pl.playlist_count*100.0}%)</summary>
     <template x-for='(v, index) in pl.entries' :key='index'>
     <div><span x-text='v.title'></span></div>
  </template>
  `"></details>
   </div>
  </template>
 </div>
```

full code here: https://github.com/chapmanjacobd/lb-lite/tree/main/client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed `app.view.table` is not reactive. For this purpose you can use the [`Alpine.store()`](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-store) which is externally accessible and reactive as well:

```
Alpine.store('table', [])

updateView: function () {
  Alpine.store('table', alasql('select * from videos'))
}
```

And in the template just use `$store.table`:

```
<template x-for="(pl, index) in $store.table" :key="index">
```